# Struggling to understand how to implement the Command Pattern Design in Java

Tags: java, command-pattern

As part of a project I have to refactor some code and I think I'm supposed to implement a Command Pattern Design, but I've looked at it from multiple angles and keep running into problems. So far I'm just trying to create something from scratch that's small but has all the features I think it'll need.

I need to create a program that can run an editor, repeatedly asks for commands from the user, parses those commands and calls the appropriate function until the 'quit' command is called and then the program exits. Some features needed are: a 'currentImage' that is being worked (example commands might be, open, save, mono, etc.), a 'cache' where images worked on can be stored (where I can 'get' and 'put' images to), a command such as 'above' that places one image above another.

If I have an Editor class that might look like this:

```
 public class Editor {
      private ArrayList<Image> cache;
      private Image currentImage;

      private Parser parser;

      public Editor(){
           cache = new ArrayList<Image>();
           parser = new Parser();
      }

      public void edit() {
           boolean finished = false;

           while (!finished) {
                command = parser.getCommand();
                finished = command.execute(command.getArgs())
           }
      }

      public boolean aNormalCommand(SomeType args) {
           //Do interesting things with args
           return false;
      }

      public boolean quit(SomeType args) {
           //Check that the args make sense
           return true;
      }

      //
      // more normal functions
      //
 }
```

Things I'm stuck on:

- How to actually make it execute the required command.
- How to parse the input properly, such that I can check the user passed in a valid command. I've looked at using an enum and/or hashmap.
- How to make it simple to actually add a new feature.

When I've looked at making a Command an interface that say implements execute and undo, and then creating classes for each function that take the object, I run into the problem where the user wants to change current image - which is going to need extra stuff to switch an image out and in, and then new objects carrying the new object for the right object.

When I've thought about how to implement lambdas I'm not sure how to make it work on the correct object. And when I look at reflection, somehow my command needs to figure out which object is supposed to be acted upon and I don't know how the parser could figure that out.

As far as 'undo' goes I thought about having an ArrayList that holds the history of filters, and an undo operating simply makes the last one the current one (which also solves the problem of having non-undoable methods)

Hopefully you'll tell me my Editor class shouldn't look like this and everything will fall into place.

Comment: I don't quite follow what problems you see with a class representing a "change current image" command.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Because that class (that changes the current image) would need to hold the object that's calling the class (the editor). Is that possible?

Comment: Why?  Why does one kind of Command need to hold a reference to the editor to which it applies, if other kinds of Commands do not?  I think you're making some implementation assumptions here that aren't obligatory.  Nevertheless, yes, it is possible for a command object to hold a reference to the editor to which it is targeted.  It would even get that automatically if its class were an inner class of the `Editor`.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm I'm looking at buyStock.java and sellStock.java. They both hold a Stock. Which in my case would be the Editor or the Image. and it needs it there in order to execute.

Comment: I'm not sure I like that example very well.  I also don't think it's a very good analog to the program you're working on.  In any event, although your Command objects do need to know what `Editor` to operate on, they don't necessarily need it to be a member variable.  It could instead be supplied as an argument to their `do()` and `undo()` methods, which would tie up the whole thing as a nice, clean inversion of control.

Answer (score 0):

Your editor class has to hold the fields necessary to perform the commands you want.

> Some features needed are: a 'currentImage' that is being worked (example commands might be, open, save, mono, etc.),

You have a current image in your Editor class.  It might need to be a BufferedImage so you can perform certain commands.

> a 'cache' where images worked on can be stored (where I can 'get' and 'put' images to),

One way to create a cache is to have a List of BufferedImages.

> a command such as 'above' that places one image above another.

Now, a BufferedImage has to have position information.  You probably need to make a subclass just to hold a Point or a Rectangle for the position information and a BufferedImage.

Once you have a class that holds all the fields necessary, including any subclasses, then you can create an interface for your commands.  Here's one example.

```
public interface Command {

    public boolean isCommand(String command);
    public boolean processCommand(String command);
    public int executeCommand();

}
```

The isCommand method identifies the command.  "Undo" is one example.  The Undo class would return true for the "Undo" command string.

The processCommand method parses the command.  "Move image 3 to position 5" is an example of a command that must be parsed.  If the command parses and verifies correctly, return true, else return false.

The executeCommand executes the command.  Some indicator is returned to indicate that the command executed correctly.  I used an int.  You can use an enum.

The Editor class would be passed to the concrete classes implementing this Command interface through the constructor.

In one of your model class, you create a List of Command instances. You then add your concrete classes that implement your Command interface to the List.

You process your commands like this:

```
public int processCommand(String command) {
    for (Command commandObject : listOfCommands) {
        if (commandObject.isCommand(command)) {
            if (commandObject.processCommand(command)) {
                int response = commandObject.executeCommand();
                return response;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return -2;
}
```